# Trouble with constraints on UIImageView embedded inside UIScrollView (SWIFT)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I am having trouble with the adding constraints in Swift programmatically, I have created and added as UIImageView inside the ScrollView. I would like each image in the scroll view to be as big as the width and a height of 128px.

[Here is what the simulator looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKzey.png). I am trying to create a scrolling carousel essentially using

```
import UIKit

 class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.




   self.scrollView.frame =  CGRectMake( 0, 0, self.view.frame.width, 128)

    let scrollViewHeight = self.scrollView.frame.height

    let scrollViewWidth = self.scrollView.frame.width

    var imgOne = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, scrollViewWidth, scrollViewHeight))

    var imgTwo = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(scrollViewWidth, 0, scrollViewWidth, scrollViewHeight))

    imgOne.image = UIImage(named: "Slide 1")
    imgTwo.image = UIImage(named: "Slide 4")




    self.scrollView.addSubview(imgOne)
    self.scrollView.addSubview(imgTwo)

    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.width * 2, self.scrollView.frame.size.height)



    // let horizonalContraints = NSLayoutConstraint(item: scrollView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)




   // NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([horizonalContraints])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try capturing view hierarchy when you run app to see whether problem is with scrollview, or with image view. (just search in Xcode capture view ...)
I also experienced this kind of bug when I was embedding view inside another using constrains.

Try also NSLog frames of each element if you haven't already.

Hope it helps you solve the problem.